# Escaping backslashes in Visual Studio Code workspace settings variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a Visual Studio Code workspace file where I'd like to be able to use the predefined ${workspaceFolder} variable, as documented here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

> ${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code

However, the command requires the variable to have backslashes escaped.  This setting works with hard-coded, manually-escaped, absolute paths:

```
"settings": {
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile",
        "C:\\path\\to\\project\\.pylintrc",
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.append('C:\\\\path\\\\to\\\\project\\\\')"
    ]
}
```

In this case, `${workspaceFolder} = C:\path\to\project`

My goal is to have something that looks like this:

```
"settings": {
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\.pylintrc",
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.append('${workspaceFolder}')"
    ]
}
```

However, the code above does not work because the second use requires backslashes to be escaped.

Anyone know if there is a way to do this in VS Code?

Comment: Have you tried using `/` rather then `\ `? you should be able to use `/` if we are talking about a path that is local to the pc

Comment: Thanks, @Nifim.  I confirmed that I can replace the '\\' and '\\\\' with '/' in the hard-coded example, which looks a lot nicer.  It doesn't fully solve the problem though, because the ${workspaceFolder} variable still uses backslashes. If there was some way to replace backslashes in that variable with forward slashes, that would work.  I haven't found a way to perform any substitution on variables though..

Comment: Try putting an `r` before the workspace string like so `append( r'${workspaceFolder}')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `${workspaceFolder}` string to a raw string for python when you run the `sys.path.append` function. To do that you need to add a `r` before the opening `'`

Example:

```
"settings": {
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\.pylintrc",
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.append(r'${workspaceFolder}')"
    ]
}
```